# Can I make a view have a transparent background but make it's subviews visible?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nsview

I have an NSScrollView with an NSCollectionView inside of it.

I want the NSScrollView's background to be transparent but when I set the opacity to 0 it just creates a giant white box for the background.

This NSScrollView is inside of an NSView with a background that I want to see, so the giant white box is unacceptable.

Now an alternative approach I tried was changing the blending mode of the NSScrollView to softlight but when I do this the subviews are also put on softlight. Is there anyway to make it so the subviews show up as normal but the NSScrollView's background is transparent?

Comment: Did you try unchecking "draw background" in the NSScrollView's nib attributes?

Comment: Yeah I figured it out. Thanks though.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me at all on 10.10 :(